# Failed Create AMI With Ansible Playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I've try to create AMI using ansible-playbook, i've already export aws secret key & access into path and ansible version is 2.0.0.

```
- hosts: localhost
    tasks:
    - name: create ami
      ec2_ami:
        region: "ap-southeast-1"
        instance_id: "i-c2xxxx"
        name: "jmicro"
        wait: yes
      register: ami
```

but when i run command : ansible-playbook create_ami.yml, i get this error :

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, create_ami.yml

Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 5, column 1

    ec2_ami:
        region: "ap-southeast-1"
```

is there something wrong with my yaml script ? but when i run :

```
# ansible localhost -m ec2_ami -a "instance_id=i-c2xxxx region=ap-southeast-1 wait=yes name=jmicro"
```

it's success !!

Answer (score 1):

There are some strange characters in front of `tasks`. Don't know what that is but when I copy your code block and paste it into my editor, then try to remove the whitespaces with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, it actually deletes the characters on the right side of the curser.

YAML only allows whitespaces for indenting lines. I think that is the issue here. And `tasks` needs to be on the same level as `hosts`. Other than that your definition looks OK to me.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: create ami
      ec2_ami:
        region: "ap-southeast-1"
        instance_id: "i-c2xxxx"
        name: "jmicro"
        wait: yes
      register: ami
```

Comment: bro thx for your correction ... i think because i put tab key to indent spaces while using vim, it's running well now